# CSS border solution

Tags: css

[image]i got a simple code, few blocks with red border. I need change border color on hover for example on blue, but border on all blocks must be 1px. Blocks cant move, cant be more than 150px height and width. Red border cant be under the blue one. So as the result on hover we must see block w150px + h150px border only blue, no move, no any change.
Can some1 help ?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper    {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 450px;
    width: 100%;
 }   
 .wrapper__square {
        flex: 0 0 150px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper__square:hover {
         border: 1px solid blue;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="current" class="wrapper__square one"></div>
        <div class="wrapper__square two"></div>
        <div class="wrapper__square tree"></div>
        <div class="wrapper__square four"></div>
        <div class="wrapper__square five"></div>
        <div class="wrapper__square six"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use `outline` to imitate the effect of a border:

```
.wrapper__square {
   outline-color: red;
   outline-width: 1px;
   outline-style: solid;
   outline-offset: -1px;
}

.wrapper__square:hover {
   outline-color: blue;
}
```

`outline-offset` is used to move the outline so that it is contained within the element.

The above implementation imitates a border, but it will be located on the inside of the div. Also, another bonus about outline is that unlike border, the outline can overlap with other content, which can prevent unwanted element shifting.

Comment: i use already outline and box-shadow, but still got 1 issue. Some blue otlines on hover situated under the red one. Its not acceptable in my case. i try already use "+" selector,but promlem is i can fix that promblem only with borders of element 4 and 5, but cant with 1 and 4

Comment: i add a picture how must hover looks like, but still have problem as i sad with bottom border

Answer (score 0):

okey, finally i got acceptable result. Can't make it by foreign methods, but work fine.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper    {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.wrapper td {
        position: relative;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid red;
}       
.wrapper td:hover:after{
                position: absolute;
                top: -1px;
                left: -1px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                content: '';
                border: 1px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="wrapper">
        <tr class=wrapepr__row>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class=wrapepr__row>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```